# Limit the number of elements in List(Of String) in VB.NET

Tags: string, vb.net, list

I am cycling through a log file using `StreamReader.ReadLine()` looking for errors. When I find an error, I need to look at preceding lines to see what happened.

But since StreamReader won't let me read previous lines, I need to keep a record of previous lines.

I've been using `lineStrings.Add(readfile.ReadLine())` where `lineStrings` is a `List(Of String)` and `readFile` is a `StreamReader`.

This works great, but some of my log files are massive, so the list gets way too big. The error details are only in the previous 10 lines of any error, so is there any way to have the List(Of String) discard old lines when I add a new one when the list is already 10 elements?

I've looked at stacks and queues but am just confusing myself.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't u keep a simple scalar buffer (e.g. a string variable) to keep last 10 lines in it? Just assign it a new value in each iteration. i.e. u just strip the first line from this string value from top end and append the current one at the bottom. A `StringBuilder` may make things even easier.

Comment: Yes, use a `Queue(Of String)`.  Enqueue() to put a line of text in it, if its Count is larger than 10 then Dequeue().  Easy peasy, you'll make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Something on the following lines (hand-typed pseudocode, but u should be able to translate):

```
Dim SB As New StringBuilder
Dim LineCount as Integer = 0

Do While Stream.End
  Dim CurLine = ReadNextLineFromYourStream()
  SB.Append(CurLine)
  LineCount += 1
  If LineCount > 10 Then RemoveFirstLineFromSB
  If ErrorFound Then YouHaveYourLast10LinesIn(SB.ToString())
Loop
```

Removing first line from `StringBuilder` is as simple as `SB.Remove(0, SB.IndexOf(vbCrLf))` or whatever line-terminator you're using.

Comment: I've realised that I can do what you've suggested with the List(Of String) by using lineStrings.RemoveAt(0) to remove the first item. Thanks!

Comment: @Paul: Yep. A `Queue` might be easier and more efficient to use as suggested by Hans. `List` is okay too.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a StringBuffer class to only keep the last n strings.

```
Public Class StringBuffer
    implements IEnumerable(Of String)

    Private _internalBuffer As LinkedList(Of String)

    Public Sub New(ByVal size As Integer)
        Size = size
        _internalBuffer = New LinkedList(Of String)()
    End Sub

    Public Property Size As Integer

    Public Sub Add(ByVal str As String)
        _internalBuffer.AddFirst(str)
        If _internalBuffer.Count > Size Then _internalBuffer.RemoveLast()
    End Sub

    Public Function GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator(Of String) Implements IEnumerable(Of String).GetEnumerator
        Return _internalBuffer.GetEnumerator()
    End Function

    Private Function IEnumerable_GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator Implements IEnumerable.GetEnumerator
        Return _internalBuffer.GetEnumerator()
    End Function
End Class
```

We use a `LinkedList` as the internal data-structure to achieve O(1) time complexity for the Add operation (which also might remove old item).
When iterated you will get the **latest** entries first.

Answer (score 1):

From your description of the process, you could use a [List(Of String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Collections.Generic.List%601);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) or a [Queue(Of String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Collections.Generic.Queue%601);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) to hold the last `N` lines read from the Log file.

A `List(of String)` is probably a little faster than a `Queue(Of String)`, if performance is a concern.

An example using the two classes:
Note: when an error is found, the List (`lineStrings`) will have `MaxElements + 1` elements. The last one is the line containing the error, the remaining `MaxElements` lines contain the error description or whatever it is.

```
Dim MaxElements As Integer = 10
Dim lineStrings As List(Of String) = new List(of String)

'(...)
'Open the file stream using a StreamReader
lineStrings.Add(readfile.ReadLine())
If lineStrings.Last().Contains([Error]) Then
    'Process the error using the lineStrings items
    'Clear the List if the content is not required anymore
    lineStrings.Clear()
End If
If lineStrings.Count > MaxElements Then lineStrings.RemoveAt(0)
```

You could do the same with a `Queue(Of String)`:

```
Dim lineStrings As Queue(Of String) = new Queue(of String)(MaxElements)

lineStrings.Enqueue(readfile.ReadLine())
If lineStrings.Last().Contains([Error]) Then
    'Process the error using the lineStrings items
    'Clear the Queue if needed/preferable
    lineStrings.Clear()
End If
If lineStrings.Count > MaxElements Then lineStrings.Dequeue()
```

A speed test, adding `100,000` and `1,000,000` elements, checking for errors and removing the 10th element from the List, no processing (compiled as release, using the .exe file):

```
100,000 elements (average):
List(Of String):  21 ms
Queue(Of String): 29 ms

1,000,000 elements (average):
List(Of String):  206 ms
Queue(Of String): 298 ms
```